# how to plot a mean data histogram in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogramm that look like that:
[image]

You see, for each year (X) there are several Y, so the histogram has overlapping bars. 
How can i build it for only max Y? and for the mean?

My code is:

```
  My dataframe is:
    Data  Amount
    1996    65155
    1984    88705
    1996    115551
    2010    87222
    1995    3043
    1994    54789
    2007    87655
    1996    55189
    2005    34914
    2005    122643
    1995    111700
    1996    64065
    1995    76783
    1994    85687
    1995    88515
    1996    48352
    1995    315025
    1995    80074
    1995    133998
    2000    40918
    2000    108585
    1996    119506
    2003    105385
    2003    93374
    1996    63970
    1995    15261
    1996    128078
    1995    83593
    1994    54544
    2006    108167
    1996    141421
    2005    83725

year=df[['Year']].as_matrix()
amount=df[['Amount']].as_matrix()

stepsize = 10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(year, amount, width=1)
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Amount')
ax.set_title(r'Amount - year')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
plt.show()
```

Comment: you need to make a reproducible example (include code that generates representative data from scratch w/o local files, connections to databases, etc)

Comment: ok, the question is edited

Comment: Like I said, "without local files", You're the only person in the world with `Data.csv`.

Comment: Well that's better, but it's still up to the people who are going to help you to copy and paste that data into a text file or use `pandas.read_clipboard` themselves. It'd be ideal if you used a `StringIO` object to eliminate that friction.

Comment: well its a question of getting data :) But do you have any theoretical ideas how can i do what i need?..

Comment: You need to put in the effort to ask easily reproducible and verifiable questions. It's not up to the people *trying to help _you_* to take stabs in the dark are reproducing your data structures. My answer also shows you how to use the `StringIO` module to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're reading your data with pandas, you can use the dataframe to group the data, aggregate as you wish, and plot those values. I use the `max` value in the example below, but you could also use the `mean`, `min`, ... whatever.

Also note how I use the `StringIO` to make this example completely copy/paste-able.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
Year  Amount
1996    65155
1984    88705
1996    115551
2010    87222
1995    3043
1994    54789
2007    87655
1996    55189
2005    34914
2005    122643
1995    111700
1996    64065
1995    76783
1994    85687
1995    88515
1996    48352
1995    315025
1995    80074
1995    133998
2000    40918
2000    108585
1996    119506
2003    105385
2003    93374
1996    63970
1995    15261
1996    128078
1995    83593
1994    54544
2006    108167
1996    141421
2005    83725
""")

df = pandas.read_csv(datafile, sep='\s+')
ax = df.groupby(by=['Year']).max().plot.bar(legend=False)
ax.set_ylabel("Amount")
```

[image]